# How do I extract an item in a list if it has a certain string in python?

Tags: python

I have a list with many items in each entry delimited by `[]`. e.g.,

```
['1', 'pbkdf2_sha256$100000$sk3ONL23432fsdgUsHM62xa9XJHL+LkJHhK3cFGj8LYWGtOd8HC7Hs=',
'2018-09-25 19:32:41', '0', '', '', 'bob@trellis.law', 'Bob', 'Simon', 
'bob@trellis.law', '1', '0', '2016-12-30 17:43:41', 'Bob Simon', 'Bob', '0', '1', 
'', '[]', '', '0', '1', '0', '1', '', '', '1', '14', '191', '1', '0', '1', '0', '', 
'', '', '0']
```

I want to find entries that contain this regex, and then capture the *entire* row in a variable:

```
r = re.compile(r'\w+\+\d+@trellis\.law')
```

I have unsuccesfully tried:

```
def import_csv(csv_file):
    name_entries = []
    with open(csv_file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        name_entries.append(list(reader))
    return name_entries


def exclude_regex_users(name_entries):
    pulled_names = []
    r = re.compile(r'\w+\+\d+@trellis\.law')

    reader = csv.reader(name_entries)

    for read in reader:
        n = r.match(read)
        if n:
            pulled_names.append(n.group())

    print(pulled_names)
```

I get a `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not list (did you open the file in text mode?)`.

Argh.

Comment: `list(reader)` is a list, why are you appending it to another list instead of just returning that list as is?

Comment: Why are you alling `csv.reader(name_entries)`? The argument to `csv.reader()` should be a file, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `import_csv` should not wrap the list in another list, it should just return the list of rows.

```
def import_csv(csv_file):
    name_entries = []
    with open(csv_file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        return list(reader)
```

Second, `exclude_entries` doesn't need to use `csv`, that was already used when the data was imported, and `name_entries` is the list of rows.

Third, you should only be matching against the list element that contains the email address.

You can use `filter()` to filter the list, rather than a loop.

```
def exclude_regex_users(name_entries):
    r = re.compile(r'\w+\+\d+@trellis\.law')
    pulled_names = filter(lambda row: r.match(row[6]) or r.match(row[9]), name_entries)

    print(pulled_names)
```

Comment: Thanks -- this is so helpful. Why do you call out `row[6]` in the `exclude_regex_users` function?

Comment: And how do I see what's in `pulled_names` when I return it?
`return pulled_names`

I changed it to `row for row in name_entries` and I got no matches. I know that there are four matches in the list.

Comment: I looked at the list in the question, the email is in element 6.

Comment: `filtered_names = exclude_regex_users(name_entries)` then `print(filtered_names)`

Comment: BTW, this function doesn't exclude the users that match the regex, it returns them.

Comment: I changed it to row for row in name_entries and I got no matches. I know that there are four matches in the list.

Comment: The argument to `r.match()` has to be a string. `row` is a list, `row[6]` is the element with the email.

Comment: I've changed it to match both fields that contain emails.

Comment: I want to pull the entire entry if the text has what's in the regex. Any idea how?

Comment: You want the whole row, or just the emails? Your original code used `.group(0)`, which is just the matched text, not the whole row.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show what you expect `pulled_names` to be?

Comment: The whole row. I edited the question to reflect that. Thank you!

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a ton for your help.